# list of value as value of aninput variables for ML classification

Tags: python, regression, classification

I have a dataset that contains features and samples. The value of each corresponding sample is a list of float. Which method can i use for prediction(classification or regression). The dataset looks like:

```
      feat1         feat2            y
```

s1 [1.0 3.5 6.7]     [0.0 -0.5 100.7]    1
s2 [-2.4 5.9 -8.9]   [1.0 -2.4 8.9]      0

y is the predicted variable.
s represents each sample
feat represents each feature

Thanks.

I considered each column of feature as new feature and its gave me many new features for the new dataset.

Answer (score 0):

**Regression** would be a good choice if there is a **trend** you can model in your data. You have to plot your points to figure that out.

In this case **classification** is not a option given the continuous nature of your target variable (y).